# Почему видает ошибку при передаче параметров в конструктор класа?

Tags: c++

У меня есть код и мне видает ошибку когда я в конструктор передаю значения почему видает ошибку и как исправить ее?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>


class TwoDShape {

double width; double height;

public:
void setw(double w) { width = w; }
void seth(double h) { height = h; }

double getw() { return width; }
double geth() { return height; }

};


class Triangle :public TwoDShape {

char style[20];
public:

Triangle(char *sto, double w,double h) {

    setw(w);
    seth(h);
    strcpy_s(style, sto);

}
double area() {
    return getw() * geth() / 2;
}


void showstyle() {
    cout << style << endl;
}


};


int main() {

SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);

Triangle t1("garo", 15, 15);
cout<<t1.area();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Triangle(char *sto, double w,double h)
```

поменять на

```
Triangle(const char *sto, double w,double h)
```

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите, объявив

```
Triangle(char *sto, double w,double h)
```

вы говорите тем самым: "я **буду менять** строку, на которую указывает `sto`". Неважно, делаете вы это или нет — вы подали заявку.

А передаете *литерал* `"garo"`. Но менять литерал нельзя! отсюда и все проблемы.

Проще всего — раз вы не меняете строку `sto` — сказать об этом прямо:

```
Triangle(const char *sto, double w,double h)
```